# Why does omnibus chef still use Ruby 1.9.1? When will it upgrade to use 2.0?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Ruby 2.0 has been around for a while, and it has been proved by many projects to have had many improvements compared to earlier versions, especially performance improvement. Why does omnibus chef still use ruby 1.9.1? When will it upgrade to use Ruby 2.0?

Comment: Chef installed by Omnibus in fact uses Ruby 1.9.3. It contains the string `1.9.1` in its paths because thats the ABI version, not necessarily the actual ruby version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does the current Ubuntu release not use the very latest kernel?

Well.. That's the way it goes, not everything can be always at the latest version.

But Ruby 2.0 support is [planned](https://github.com/opscode/opscode-summit-2013/wiki/Wednesday-Azure-1000#chef-12-features) for Chef 12.

Comment: Chef 12, good to know that, thanks